# An answer of mine was deleted as "offensive" with a penalty of 100 points. how can i appeal it?

Tags: discussion, support

It is in perfectly respectful language and is of crucial importance.  I'd be happy to reproduce it here and get more opinions.

The deleted answer can be read [here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22442/how-unity-among-followers-of-various-systems-philosophies-can-be-achieved) (for those who can see it)

Comment: That can't be done. Don't post abusive posts from now on. That's how to go on. To remind again.. This site is not a place to put your hate against a sect you don't believe.

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22175). A user loses 100 rep if his post gets "6 rude flags from users" or "one rude flag from mod". In this case, rep can't be restored.

Comment: The answer you had posted was sounding rude or offensive.

Comment: A user loses 100 rep if his post gets "6 rude flags from users" or "one rude flag from mod". In this case, rep can't be restored.@The Destroyer  This is unbelievable.  So six users or a moderator can boot someone out of here arbitrarily.  There is a Hindu sect that calls Lord Siva a "jivatma" subject to karma and death like everybody else and His devotees cannot call it out - is that it?

Comment: @thedestroyer is it mod or even someone with mod privileges?

Comment: That is not done @SK You can't write such posts and expect at the same time that they will stay. So, just be a lil clever and understand what is expected of you. I think you can be a good member. Just show some prudence and have some patience.

Comment: And as regards the 100 points u lost, they can be earned in a day too. By writing good Qs and As.

Answer (score 5):

The post deleted was not a question it is an answer. The post which was deleted by community which means flagged by users as abusive. The post was not in a perfectly respectful language.

The words used are against Vaishnavites and the followers of Hare Krishna movement i.e., Gaudiya Vaishnavites .

> All Hindu sects except Vaishnavites have long given up medieval sectarian hostilities. **It is only Vaishnavites whose core ideology is the denigration of the Gods of other Hindu sects that are the problem. the problem has become particularly virulent now that Gaudiyas have taught Siva-hatred to westerners through the Hare Krishna movement. The Vaishnavite + Hare Krishna combination is a deadly threat to Hinduism** and it has to be dealt with head-on.

According to the '[Be Nice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)' policy of Stack Exchange,

> **Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all**. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)

This passage alienates the users of Vaishnavism or offensive for the users who follow that post. Calling them a deadly threat to Hinduism is definitely offensive.

When your post is marked as abusive, then you will be deducted 100 reputation points as a penalty and they can't be redeemed as said in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/357396) mother meta post. If this behaviour continues repeatedly, you will be suspended.

So, please be nice to all the users on the site whether they are of any sect.

Comment: On a related note, if this is answer is disrespectful to a sect, aren't the answers being called out in the meta post (the one on interpolations) disrespectful to a different sect? The difference is the choice of words - one is harsh and the other is mild but the objective of both is the same.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Are you relating calling interpolations and a threat to religion same? Everyone agrees that Puranas have the interpolations. Any one can say that. But calling a threat to religion is not the same. If you say they are the same, then I can't speak with you more regarding this one.

Comment: @moonstar2001, I agree with whatever mention in this answer about 'Be Nice'. The other post on interpolation is a very subjective & delicate matter. In fact from main SO standards, it would be treated as "non-issue". Of course we all understand that the religions & its sensibility can't be matched 1:1 with technical stuff. Similarly, the post deleted here, is pure hate. We should not even compare this and that (interpolation etc.).

Comment: @Rickross I added the remaining part. It doesn't matter what was the remaining part even when there is even single word abusive. However, this is 95% of the post. There is only one sentence which says this"
Sects/religions that aren't in conflict can live in peace together, although their beliefs are different. Jains live in total peace with Hindus." And the rest of it is this hate speech.

Comment: @iammilind You did not understand what moonstar is trying to say. Both users motive is the same- to demean one or the other sects. Now, while one is doing it crudely and openly , the other one is doing it by using subtle means. Both users intent is same but methods are different.

Comment: moonstar2001 and @Rickross, If you think that post is disrespectful to a sect and compares with this post, Are you ready to take that post to main meta and I will take this one to main meta. I will convince them that this is rude and can you do it?

Comment: @NogShine Is this a Q or A that we are discussing here? OP says one of his Qs was deleted.

Comment: @Rickross It is an answer to Rohit's question [How unity among followers of various systems/philosophies can be achieved?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22442/5212)

Comment: OH @NogShine then why OP is saying it's a Q? Anyways that's why i was confused.

Comment: @iammilind What Rickross said.